# Regex not working in numeric input field

Tags: regex, html, forms, input

I am trying this html code to limit the input field to nine-digit rule, with a maximum value possible of 999999999.

```
<input name="field" type="number" max="999999999" pattern=".{9,9}">
```

However this code will check the maximum but will allow things like:

```
9
999 
9999
99999
```

When what should be allowed is:

```
123456789
111111111
789531156
```

What is wrong?

I am only interested in html5 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pattern` attribute doesn't seem to work for inputs of type "number" (at least in Chrome). However, you can set the min value like this:

```
<input name="field" type="number" max="999999999" min="100000000">
```

Or use a simple "text" input like this:

```
<input name="field" type="text" pattern="\d{9}">
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/8NW6t/)